Vuetify v-chip close - icon is not showing up
I looked at this question and it's no help:
vuetify v-chip close icon not showing
I have the same issue, here's how I'm creating vuetify:
// Styles
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
export const vuetify = createVuetify({
  // theme: {
  //   defaultTheme: 'dark',
  // },
  components,
  directives,
})

Here's the main:
/**
 * main.ts
 *
 * Bootstraps Vuetify and other plugins then mounts the App`
 */

// Plugins
import { registerPlugins } from '@/plugins'
import {getCurrentUser, VueFire, VueFireAuth} from 'vuefire'

// Components
import App from './App.vue'

// Composables
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import {fbapp} from "./fstore";
import {router} from "./router";
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import {vuetify} from "./vuetify";
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

// Composables

const vfOptions = {
  firebaseApp: fbapp,
  modules: [ VueFireAuth() ]
}
const pinia = createPinia()

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(vuetify)
app.use(VueFire, vfOptions)
app.use(router)
app.use(pinia)
getCurrentUser().then(() => app.mount('#app'))

Here's the chip code:
<v-chip class="ma-2" v-for="p in parts" close @click:close="() => alert(`Close ${p}`) ">
    {{ p }}
</v-chip>

I figure I'm missing a font icon set somehow, and I've tried all kinds of imports and stuff. The solution from the question above says to pass iconfont to the createVuetify method, but that's not even a valid option anymore.
I use v-icons and the material icons work properly, so whatever I do needs to not break that.
What do I need to add here?

Try following this link https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#font-awesome
I think your missing something related to the icons in your createVuetify({})
